# Microsoft Access: Moving Form to shared drive, VBA code not working once there

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2013

Hello and thank you for helping!

I created an Access form that has a few button on it that when clicked format a textbox below the buttons (basically different colors).  The idea is for employees to not lose track of important issues to discuss while they are on a phone call with clients.  I know Access is typically for database-ing if you will, but I don't need it to track anything or update records as there are none.

This works fine on my computer, however when I try to send it via email or put it on a shared drive, the form appears, but the buttons do not work. I even tried copying the database file along with it to the shared drive, but it still did not work. It seems the VBA code that is connected to the button clicks does not work on a shared drive.

The drive itself is mapped to a letter (Y) on my computer, but may be mapped to Z or another letter on employee computers. Would this be the issue? Or better yet, is there a way to isolate the form so it works like a standalone program on each new machine using it?

I am relatively new to Access, what am I missing?

TL;DR Press button on Access form, textbox turns blue. Send to friends, they try to do the same, nothing happens.

As always, thank you for your time!

EDIT: There are two scenarios that can happen when another user tries to access this form:
1) The form appears perfectly, but when they click the buttons, nothing happens, no text box is formatted.
or
2) It throws this error: 'blah blah drive X' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Comment: Please add to your question the code which is not working, and specify if "not working" means "it's crashing" or "it's doing nothing". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the UNC (Universal Naming Convention) instead of the drive letter (Y:)

The format is below.

\servername\sharename\path\filename

The servername and sharename information can be found on "My Computer" for Windows

Comment: I attempted to update to that format via the Linked Table Manager or deleting and re-linking to it by typing in the UNC manually, for some reason it still wouldn't work on anyone elses computer.

Comment: Could it be an Access Security Setting that the employee needs to adjust in order to use the VBA code.  Can the employee see the VBA code in the database copy you provide to them?

Comment: Yes, if they open the file in design view, the code is visible

Comment: Has the employee tried copying the database to their hard drive and testing the form function?  This would help answer the question about the shared drive being the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, even after copying it to the hard drive, it will still throw that "invalid file path" error

Comment: Will you add the code behind the button causing the error?

Comment: I think you are right, the shared does seem to be the main cause of the issue.  I had one of the employees update the file path to what they have their shared drive listed as, and it worked.  I'm just wondering if there is a way to send everyone this file without having to have them manually change the drive reference location

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be throwing the error, but here's a sample of what they all look like: `Private Sub actbutton_Click()
If actbox2.BackColor = vbWhite Then
With Form_alerthelps.actbox
    .BackColor = RGB(29, 79, 246)
    .ForeColor = vbWhite
    .FontSize = 9
    .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
    .Value = "ACTIVATION"
    .FontName = "Arial Black"
End With

With actbox2
    .BackColor = RGB(29, 79, 246)
End With
Else
    actbox.BackColor = vbWhite
    actbox2.BackColor = vbWhite
End If

End Sub`

Comment: If the employee was successful in changing the file path to their shared drive then you could create a text box and have the employee provide the file path and then reference the text box as the file path

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this was solved! I changed the Form Record source to be the linked table, and it worked. It was still referencing a table on the computer I created it on.  Thank you to everyone who helped!